# Understanding Autolayout Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am new to autolayout and I want to understand the constraints of autolayout.

my question is ->

When we apply constraints between two objects it gives you 3 options in relation tab which are equal, less than or equal to and greater than equal to.
So I want to understand when to use less than or equal to and greater than equal to sonstraint.

If possible please help me with some small demo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

suppose you want a UILabel to resize maximum height to 80 pixels depending upon its inner content and if more test are displayed in the label then it should truncate its tail but should not increase its height because you have other elements on screen which will not look good if the label will increase more then that. So here you should use height <= 80. So if you set some minimum value of the label like height >= 40 so if the text of the label is not enough to fit in 40 height then it will stay 40 pixels but if text increases then it will increase max up to 80. So here you came to now about the use of greater then or equal to also. Like if you want a element to be minimum some value and if its resizing at runtime then should not be less then any value, then you can use those constraints. I can describe in brief if needed. Thanks.

Comment: What about vertical spacing and horizontal spacing constraint. In that constraints also we have those relations so how to use them actually

Comment: Thats also useful. When suppose you want to control spacing between two resizing UILabel then those are useful. Just visualize the 2 label which can vertically increase height according to its text content but gap should not be less then 5 pixel. Here you can use those. Similar with any situation. Auto-Layout is completely understandable if you can visualize what the possibilities and property can do.